# Why is the PHP program not getting variables passed by GET?

Tags: php, get

Here's the file.php that I wrote to get the username and password but for some reason it is not working.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET["submit"])) {

    $username = $_GET["username"];
    $username = $_GET["password"];
    print "Your username: $username";
    print "And password: $password";
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head><title>OHO</title></head>
  <body>
    <form action="form.php" type="get">
    Username:<input type="text" name="username"><br />
    Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br />
    Submit   <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is why copy and paste can be more time consuming than just writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your conditional statement `if(isset($_GET["submit"]))` is based on a named element, therefore nothing will be executed from inside it.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

name it

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

Plus, `$username = $_GET["password"];` needs to be `$password = $_GET["password"];`

you've declared the same variables for both.

also `type="get"` which should be `method` and not `type` - Type is for the elements and not the form's method itself.

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text which is not recommended and extremely unsafe, while sending that information via a GET method; use POST.

For a safer method, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 4):

at line 4  , 5 you have defined both variable name to `$username`

```
$username = $_GET["username"];
$username = $_GET["password"];
```

it must be :

```
$username = $_GET["username"];
$password = $_GET["password"];
```

next fault is define form method :

```
<form action="form.php" method="get">
```

finaly its recommended to use `strip_tags()` for preventing from XSS attacks

```
$username = strip_tags($_GET["username"]);
$password = strip_tags($_GET["password"]);
```

and use password encryption method for store in database

Answer (score 0):

According to all other answeres,

you also should have a look at **[FILTER_INPUT](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)**

```
$username = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'username');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'password');
```

> filter_input — Gets a specific external variable by name and optionally filters it

There you can validate emails, encode things if needed and so on